# Can boost interpocess condition variables wake spuriously?

Tags: c++, boost

The boost/thread `condition_variable` documentation notes that they may unblock spuriously, the boost/interprocess documentation for condition variables doesn't mention spurious wakeup that I could find. Do boost/interprocess condition variables (e.g `named_condition`) exhibit the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like yes. After digging through the source of boost 1.55 it appears that at least on certain platforms the interprocess condition variables are implemented using pthread condition variables, which do allow spurious wakeups.